# What is the use of "realm" in http basic/digest authentication at Client side?

Tags: java, http, authentication

Experts, I am not sure if this has been explained earlier, but what is the role of "realm" in client perspective, specially for digest authentication.

e.g Server has following information
realm : myrealm
username: username1
password : somePassword.
Authentication schema : Basic.

Now when client makes a call with header "Authorization : Basic "base64encoded_username:password", then request is successful.

How should client make use of "realm" in Http headers so that in case server has multiple realm, then server validates user ONLY against that realm.

Same doubt is for Digest authentication. Do we really need to include realm in http header we prepare for Authoriation: Digest?

I do not want to use HttpClient here.

Answer (score 0):

After reading further, I figured out that client need not pass realm in request. When client sends a request to server, server challenges back to client with an response header e.g WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="WallyWorld"[Ref](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#section-2). This information is used e.g by browser as well and they pop up a dialog with message "server says WallyWorld" which is realm name. Client has to supply userid/password for that realm